# C - Why my program isn't outputing anything?

Tags: c, if-statement, struct, scanf, strcmp

I'm very very new in programming, so i don't know how to solve the problem. As you can see, I want to make a program that outputs location that you want. There is, also, typedef struct for location variables.

```
    char location[25];
    
    printf("Which place info you want? (Home, School): ");
    scanf("%s", location[25]);
    
    if(!strcmp(location[25], "home"))
    {
        printf("%s\n", home.country);
        printf("%s\n", home.city);
        printf("%s\n", home.street);
        printf("%s\n", home.building_number);
    }
    else if(!strcmp(location[25], "school"))
    {
        printf("%s\n", school.country);
        printf("%s\n", school.city);
        printf("%s\n", school.street);
        printf("%s\n", school.building_number);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("I don't have an info about this place\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved by kaylum:
`scanf("%s", location[25]);` -> `scanf("%24s", location);` and `strcmp(location[25], "home")` -> `strcmp(location, "home")`

Answer (score 2):

Inside a declaration, the `[25]` has a completely different meaning than outside a declaration.

In the line

```
char location[25];
```

it means that you are declaring an array of size `25`. However, in the lines

```
scanf("%s", location[25]);
```

and

```
if(!strcmp(location[25], "home"))
```

the `[25]` means that you want to access a specific element in the array, in this case the 26<sup>th</sup> element in the array (arrays indexes start counting at 0, not 1).

Since the array only has 25 characters, attempting to access the 26<sup>th</sup> element will access the array out of bounds, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Even if you weren't accessing the array out of bounds, your code would still be wrong. The functions `scanf` and `strcmp` both expect a pointer to the first element of the array. Therefore, passing the value of an individual character by writing `location[25]` or `location[0]` is wrong. Instead, you should simply write `location`. That way, the array will [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471) to a pointer to the first element, i.e. to `&location[0]`.

Comment: I think you could also mention the difference between `location[n]` and `&location[n]` w.r.t. `scanf`.

Comment: @CraigEstey: I have reformulated my answer a bit to explain why `location[0]` would also be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should rather write `!strcmp(location, "home")`, because location[25] is out of bounds and causes an UB (same for the second call to strcmp).

Comment: This answer only mentions one of the two problems that were mentioned in the comments section. The other problem is equally important to fix.